# How to select individual song using individual UIButton click using MPMediaPickerController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have four UIButton to select songs from library using MPMediaPickerController.
now what i want is,
when i press UIButton1 then it should open picker for select song1.
when i press UIButton2 then it should open picker for select song2. and same for UIButton3 and UIButton4 also.

where can i change to implement above mention things.

this is my current code.

```
-(IBAction)SelectSongClick:(id)sender
{
    MPMediaPickerController *picker = [[MPMediaPickerController alloc] initWithMediaTypes:MPMediaTypeAnyAudio];
    [picker setDelegate:self];
    [picker setAllowsPickingMultipleItems: NO];
```

```
if((UIButton*)sender == btnSelect1)
{
    [playerView1 removeFromSuperview];
    [player pause];
    picker.title = @"1";
}
else if ((UIButton*)sender == btnSelect2)
{
    NSLog(@"select 2 selected");

    [playerView2 removeFromSuperview];
    [player pause];
    picker.title = @"2";
}
else if ((UIButton*)sender == btnSelect3)
{
    NSLog(@"select 3 selected");
    [playerView3 removeFromSuperview];
    [player pause];
    picker.title = @"3";
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"select 4 selected");
    [playerView4 removeFromSuperview];
    [player pause];
    picker.title = @"4";
}

[self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

}

- (void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *) collection
{   
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    MPMediaItem *item = [[collection items] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *title = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
    url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];
    [self playURL:url withPickerTag:mediaPicker.title];
    NSLog(@"URL 1 : %@",url);    
    self.sendAudio = url;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly then you want to change method: `- (void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *) collection` so, that you would be able to get selected button index from it?

Create enum above your `@interface ViewController`:

```
typedef enum {
    WaveFormType_1, //you can name these enums as you want
    WaveFormType_2,
    WaveFormType_3,
    WaveFormType_4
}WaveFormType;
```

Then create a variable `WaveFormType waveType;` and assign value to it in `-(IBAction)SelectSongClick:(id)sender` depending on what button was clicked. Then use this value.

```
- (void)mediaPicker:(MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker didPickMediaItems:(MPMediaItemCollection *) collection
{   
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];

    MPMediaItem *item = [[collection items] objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.playItem:item]
}

-(void)playItem:(MPMediaItem *)item{
     NSString *title = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
     NSURL *url = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];

     if (self.waveType == WaveFormType_1){

         // play with the first waveform type
         // label.text = title ..

     }else if(self.waveType == WaveFormType_2){

         // play with the second waveform type
         // label.text = title ..
   }
   // an so on
}
```

Comment: using that i can select individual song on individual button click event.

Comment: Thanks. this code helps me to get selectedButtonIndex.

Comment: But still selected songs returns wrong SongData information.

Comment: I don't understand what `SongData` you're talking about. What do you want to accomplish? What's the purpose of 4 different buttons selecting different files?

Comment: I have four different UIView in controller and in that four UIView i have four UIButton to select song and after selecting song i am generating waveForm of selected song using third-party plugins. that is the purpose of 4 different UIButtons.

Comment: So different buttons should generate different types of waveforms? E.g. button1 generates type1 waveform, button2 generates type2 waveform?

Comment: Thanks a lot.. this helps me lot.